# Group by Location within N Meters in PostGis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, clustering

In PostGIS, given several `Location` objects, each of which looks something like this:

```
{
        :id => 1,
  :latitude => 32.4196,
  :ll_point => "(-10111.1877176122, -5384086.44077608, 3419435.33326163)",
 :longitude => -90.1076,
:updated_at => nil,
   :user_id => 1

}
```

what would the most optimal way of generating groups of locations, with the end goal of being able to say that `User1` shared locations X, Y, and Z with `User4`. 'Sharing a location' is defined as having been within ten meters of each other.

Is there a way to do something like a group by `location within X meters`?

Answer (score 3):

If a pair-wise grouping is sufficient, then a fairly simple and high performance query will suffice

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, st_distance(a.geog, b.geog) 
FROM pts a JOIN pts b ON ST_DWithin(a.geog, b.geog, %radius)
```

If your points are lon/lat using a geography column will make things simple as above. If you're using mercator coordinates internally you'll have to apply a scaling factor of 1/cos(lat) to the distance to get a true radius search.